What could be the reasons behind biased DEPT135 and DEPT90 NMR experiments?
I am conducting DEPT135 and DEPT90 NMR experiments within the scope of structure elucidation. However, the latter experiments are giving some odd results, I mean not as expected: CH3 and CH having a phase opposite to that of CH2 in DEPT135, and DEPT90 displaying CH groups, only.
What can I do to resolve this problem, knowing that all the performance tests gave good results?

Who is responsible for the phasing? https://www.uwrf.edu/CHEM/Instrumentation/DEPT135Instructions.cfm

Yes, but the spectrum signals are so complex that you can never appropriately phase them all; when some are phased, others are out of phase.

Are the pulse-lengths calibrated?

To be honest with you, I changed the probe and used a BBFO room-temperature one. I performed all the necessary calibrations, and the DEPT spectra were just fine! So, I cannot answer your question. However, when I will get back to the Cryoprobe, I will, of course, make sure to go through the calibration of pulse length. Which I suspect was at the origin of the problem. Thank you for your help.
